# Flutter ObjectBox : (Data Observers & Rx) Refresh list of previous screen based on operation on current screen

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I am using [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) Database in Flutter.

Now I want to observe the data of a particular entity and change the list when that entity will get updated.

I saw documentation [DataObserver & Rx](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-observers-and-rx) and tried to implement it as follows.

```
Stream<Query<InvoiceList>> watchedQuery = deliveryListBox!.query(InvoiceList_.dispatch.equals(true)).watch();
sub1 = watchedQuery.listen((Query<InvoiceList> query) {
  // This gets triggered any there are changes to the queried entity types.
  // You can call any query method here, for example:
  getDataFromLocal("");
});
```

I want to update the list when **dispatch** will get changed but nothing happening by this code.

Can anyone please help to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest to use get package for asynchronous operations in Flutter, https://pub.dev/packages/get

Comment: @Pratik Butani
Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. @EktaPadaliya

Comment: Did you use ObjectBox in your project ?

Comment: Then I moved to moor database @EktaPadaliya